# Rotating a video with Python 3.4

Tags: python

I am using [moviepy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/effects.html) to try resize a video clip but every time I try I get this error. Can anyone explain how I can fix it? Thanks

My python code

```
Import everything needed to edit video clips
from moviepy.editor import *

# Load video clip
myclip = VideoFileClip("dog.mov")
myclip.resize( (460,720) ) # New resolution: (460,720)
myclip.write_videofile("resized_clip.mp4") #write new video file
```

The error

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 699, in tostring
    "Please call tobytes() instead.")
Exception: tostring() has been removed. Please call tobytes() instead.
```

Comment: https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/241

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using PIL, I would try using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/), a support fork that is maintained. MoviePY recommends you use Pillow in lieu of Pil in it's docs:

http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/install.html

> For advanced image processing you will need one or several of these
>   packages. For instance using the method clip.resize requires that at
>   least one of Scipy, PIL, Pillow or OpenCV are installed.
>
> The Python Imaging Library (PIL) or, better, its branch Pillow .

Comment: Thanks. My system seems to think Pillow is already installed but it seems moviepy insists on using PIL instead. ?